# If Gaussian and Tetrahedron smearing method lead to different Fermi energies, which one is the correct?

Tags: vasp, band-structure, density-of-states, fermi-energy, smearing

In addition to this [post](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/what-is-the-source-of-this-band-structure-and-dos-inconsistency), The used settings were :

***DOS:***

```
ISMEAR = -5
SIGMA = 0.2 (default value)
```

***BS:***

```
ISMEAR = 0
SIGMA = 0.1
```

Now, This settings have lead to the same exact Band-gap stats, but the Fermi energy isn't the same. I am wondering which one of them leads to the correct $E_{Fermi}$ value.

Could I adopt the $E_{Fermi}$ value of one calculation for the other when plotting the results as suggested [here](https://www.vasp.at/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3750) in the last answer.

Comment: 1. ISMEAR=-5 gives you the correct Fermi energy.  2. Usually, the Fermi level is set to the VBM. 3. If you shift the BS by the Fermi energy from the DOS calculation with ISMEAR=-5, you will find your Fermi level is set to VBM.

Comment: Brother @Jack I have found that this is the correct answer. You can add it as an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- 1. ISMEAR=-5 gives you the correct Fermi energy.
- 2. Usually, the Fermi level is set to the VBM.
- 3. If you shift the BS by the Fermi energy from the DOS calculation with ISMEAR=-5, you will find your Fermi level is set to VBM.